# Android Contacts - SQLite database connection fail

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to access to Android contacts directly through the database. For that I

```
SQLiteDatabase data=null;
File file = new File(".... some path ... contacts2.db");
data = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(file, null);
```

But it fails with an Exception android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException unable to open database. Why is this happening? That file exactly contains desired data.

The second question is: how can I get path to the contact's database file what probably can be different in further versions?

Answer (score 2):

Contacts in android are stores in sqlite database and file named **contacts.db**

The development tool Android Debug Bridge (ADB) can be used to extract the file from an EMULATOR

ADB can also extract the file from a phone but it must be rooted first AND the ADB drivers must be installed on your machibe as well

(you can use ContentProvider to access contacts in android.)

The **contacts.db** file is stored in the protected system memory, the file path is:

data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db

Comment: I can't see such file in my filesystem. But the  contacts2.db  file is present. I using an emulator

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to contacts database, you must have "READ_CONTACTS" permissions in manifest. The contact database is in /data/data/com.android.provider.contacts location, you can't access them without root permissions. The only solution is using ContactContract and managedQuery. I give for you code sample.

```
public void kontakt()
    {
        Cursor k = this.kontakty();
        int a = k.getCount();
        while(k.moveToNext())
        {

            String s = k.getString(k.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
            tv.append(s);
            tv.append("\n");

        }

    }




    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Cursor kontakty()
    {
        Uri u = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] cochcemy = {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}; 
        return managedQuery(u, cochcemy, null, null, null);

    }
```

I hope I helped.

Comment: Thank you for you advise, it works but my question still the same - how to perform the rawQuery against database? I have a complex sql query.  "READ_CONTACTS" permissions is already in manifest.

Comment: Read about dataabase structure here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html . You can change this line "return managedQuery(u, cochcemy, null, null, null);" to "return rawQuery("QUERY");"

Comment: no it doesn't work. Activity has no rawQuery method.  The SQLiteDatabase has.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "upgrade.db";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    public static final String AUTHOR = "author";
    public static final String ISBN = "isbn";
    public static final String CITY = "city";
    public static final String CITY2 = "city2";



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,3); 

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE books (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title TEXT ,author TEXT,isbn TEXT,city TEXT );");


        Log.v("onCreate-------","called onCreate"); 

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        android.util.Log.w("books",
        "Upgrading database, which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books");
    onCreate(db);
        Log.v("onUpgrade-------","called onUpgrade with alter"); 
    }
}
```

in other class you can call:-

```
 public void onLoad(View v)
    {

        DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sl = dbh.getReadableDatabase();


        Cursor c = sl.rawQuery("select * from books",null);

        c.moveToFirst();
        /* here your code to fetch data*/


        Toast.makeText(this,"hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sl.close();
    }
```